# @value not able to read from application.properties in springboot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying to read value from properties file using @value as follows.

```
 @Value("${abc}")
private String abc;

  public List<Record> fetchRecords(String label, String predicate) {
   System.out.println(abc);

}
```

but value of abc is coming as null. Whereas when I try to print the same using @PostConstruct, I am getting the expected value.

```
@PostConstruct
    public void postconstruct() {
        System.out.println(abc);
    }
```

Any lead why I am not able to get the value in fetchRecords() method?

For reference, here goes the code

```
@Component

public class AuditRecord {
    private String subject;
    private String predicate;
    private String oldObject;
    private String newObject;
    private String readOnlyAuthInfo;

    @Value("${registry.system.base}")
    private String registrySystemContext;

    public void record(DatabaseProvider provider) throws AuditFailedException {

        System.out.println("---registrySystemContext value showing null here---"+registrySystemContext);
       ...
     }
 @PostConstruct
    public void postconstruct() {
        System.out.println("---registrySystemContext value showing here as expected---"+registrySystemContext);
    }
}
```

The way I am calling is as follows:

```
@Component
public class RegistryDaoImpl implements RegistryDao {
...
private void addOrUpdateVertexAndEdge(Vertex v, Vertex dbVertex, GraphTraversalSource dbGraph, String methodOrigin){
...
    AuditRecord record = new AuditRecord();
                            record
                            .subject(dbVertex.label())
                            .predicate(e.label())
                            .oldObject(null)
                            .newObject(existingV.label())
                            .record(databaseProvider);
}
}
```

P.S. registry.system.base is in application.yml.

Comment: Are you importing @Value from the right package?

Comment: @Tyler I think so

Comment: You may want to double check your imports. If your IDE is automatically importing some other @Value, say from Lombok, you can expect to have a null value.

Comment: is your class defined as a `@Component`?

Comment: Do you invoke the method on a spring managed bean or via `new MyClass().fetchRecords()`? It would be helpful to post a complete example.

Comment: @sidgate yes, my class is a component

Comment: @Roland I am invoking the method using an object of the class and the class is annotated as component

Comment: are you not autowiring your Component class to the calling class? try pasting the code where you are calling AuditRecord object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to autowire `AuditRecord` and not use `new` directly. Only that way you will have your class in Spring's context. 
We don't know your exact usage of the class but you might be interested in Spring's `FactoryBean`.